# I'm using a WebView and when click in href with mailto: or tel: dont redirect to nothing in Maui

Tags: maui

I've set the AndoidManifest.xml this way but still dont work.
hrfs with mailto: or tel:  dont redirect to nothing on Maui
It is like was nothing clicked

for exemple if the page in WebView contains

```
 <a href="tel:+6494461709">61709</a>
```

When some href is click It get catch this way except mailto or tel

```
 private async void MyWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    var link = e.Url.ToUpper();
}
```

AndoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" 
               android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
               android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" 
               android:supportsRtl="true"
               android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
          android:exported="true"
          android:name=".activity.MainActivity" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data  android:scheme="mailto"/>
        <data  android:scheme="tell"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have no idea what "hrfs" is.  And "don't work" is not a very useful explanation of the problem.

Comment: href my bad sorry

Comment: do you want your app to be called when a user clicks a tel/mailto link in another app?  Or do you want to respond to those links from within your own app?

Comment: @Jason IThe webview is showing an website app that has that tel/mail links and I want the Maui app can respond to that link like it does in http/https links